# Check if max number of upload files is exceeded in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'd like to send an error message to the user if the number of files exceeds the number set in `php.ini`

I used this code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['media'])) {
    if( count($_FILES["media"]['tmp_name']) > 20 ){
        http_response_code(400);
        die("You can upload max 20 files at a time.");
    }
}
.... store each file
```

Unfortunately, when I send more than 20 files, php triggers a warning (but uses status code 200) to tell me that:

```
"<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  Maximum number of allowable file uploads has been exceeded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br
```

and than it repeats this for every file that exceeds.

I'd like to kill the script when this happens before I store any of the files and sent an appropriate message that my front end knows how to handle. How can I gain access to the number of files, before the PHP triggers it's error?

Comment: I dont think you can in PHP as PHP itself does the file uploading before it gives you control to process them. You will have to do this in javascript if anywhere

Comment: If you are talking about the `max_file_uploads` setting, then that won’t be possible at all - this check happens before your own code even runs, and in the error case it will prevent your code from running at all. Plus, the whole upload would have already happened at that point - so you should really rather check this on the client-side upfront, and not let me submit the form in that case.

Comment: just check the value of max_file_uploads BEFORE you send the data

Answer (score -2):

You can get the value of max_file_uploads by php by using "ini_get(PARAMETER)".

```
var_dump(ini_get("max_file_uploads"));
string(2) "20"
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.ini-get.php

Comment: I expect the downvote is because this doesn't solve the problem of determining whether the upload count has been exceeded.  If the client tries to upload 21 files the count() of files is still 20, which matches the max value.  What is needed is a way to ask how many were attempted to be sent.

Comment: To check if your choosen number of file uploads will be more than allowed by a rule you got to check the return value of that rule, dont you? That ist what i refered here - the if count() > x statement is already there in the question....